# How to repeatedly start an Alexa Skill in a certain timeframe

Tags: automation, alexa-skills-kit

​Hi people!

I hope someone can help me out:

I'm searching for whether (and if, then how) it's possible for a skill to start at a certain time, ask questions e.g. every 90 minutes and stop at a certain time.

Scenario would be:

"Alexa, please start my Survey at 9 AM and stop at 8 PM for 7 days. Ask me every 90 minutes."

And the skill would then activate every 90 minutes in the selected timeframe, ask a question that would e.g. be answered with yes/no and why and then stop after 7 days.

Hope I explained my problem well enough for you to understand what I want to do.

Thank you very much for your help!

Have a nice day,

Lama

Comment: Take a look at [routines](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=G202200080).  But this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/7xbsn0/can_i_get_alexa_to_run_a_skill_in_my_routine/) post seems to say it's not possible for skills yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to invoke any Alexa skill from back-end. The obvious reason for that is that Alexa is completely based on user initiated conversation and this feature violates the privacy of the user. Even the notifications service that Amazon is bring to Alexa device soon does not invoke Alexa device, it will just show a yellow light ring on devices to show that there is a pending notification for the user.